# how to make colors change smoothly when plotting in R

Tags: r, contour

**ENV**

R 3.3.1

*mini data*

```
rdn<-c(0.8,1.8,2.8)
tdn<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

idn<-matrix(c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0.5, 0.7), nrow=9, ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

*What I have now*:

*code*

```
filled.contour(tdn, rdn, idn,
    color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red")), 
    plot.title=title(main="Detail", sub="detail", 
                    xlab="t", ylab="lambda"), 
    plot.axes = { axis(side = 1, at = tdn, labels = tdn)
                  axis(side = 2, at = rdn, labels = rdn) },
    key.title=title(main="ratio"),
    key.axes = axis(4, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)))
```

**Current Result**

[image]

**Problem**

The color range is not what I want. There are borders among colors so colors do not change smoothly from deep blue to deep red.

**Expected**

[image]

**Question**

how to make colors change smoothly like my **Expeced** figure when plotting in R?  How do I remove problems above? And `rainbow` not works for me either. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Follow Haboryme's solution

[image]

The foreground not disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close to @setempler answer but you might find it a bit closer to your expected output:

```
par(fg = NA,col="black")
filled.contour(x=tdn,
               y=rdn,
               z=idn,
               color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red")), 
               plot.title=title(main="Detail", sub="detail", 
                                xlab="t", ylab="lambda"), 
               nlevels=200,
               plot.axes = { axis(side = 1, at = tdn, labels = tdn)
                 axis(side = 2, at = rdn, labels = rdn) },
               key.title=title(main="ratio"),
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice tweaking `par`!

Comment: I tried your solution. The foreground do not disappear for me after setting `fg=NA` and `col="black"`. The white lines still exists.

Comment: @NickDong that's really surprising. Have you tried after starting a new R session?

Comment: Yes, I do it after restarted R console.

Comment: @NickDong what do you get after par(fg=NA) ?

Comment: A blank Quartz. `Quartz 2[*]`

Comment: @NickDong And if you try plotting the figure again?

Comment: Get the figure with white lines. see **EDIT**

Comment: @NickDong you should get a different version, with no lines surrounding the plot or the legend.

Comment: The ticks did not show in **EDIT** but white line still exists. It is wired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134963/discussion-between-nick-dong-and-haboryme).

Comment: pdf looks better than png. More colors in Palette looks better than less colors. The more nlevels of color looks better.

Comment: @NickDong the only difference I can see is that I have R 3.3.2, however, nothing in the release notes let me believe there is anything that would justify such differences.

Comment: And one drawback of this method is any foreground lines, axes ticks, points would not be visible, even if you want to show them on the plot. right?

Comment: @NickDong indeed, contour.filled doesn't allow for full customization hence the hack. You may want to look into ggplot2 if you want to tweak the plot further.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `filled.contour` ...

- fixes the number of levels/colours between the plot and key, so experimenting with the `nlevels` argument (and `col` instead `color.palette`) results in a weird output (smoother image, but unreadable key).
- In addition, the contour lines cannot be modified. Thus, an increase to 200 levels (from initially 14 in your example) is still 'readable', but higher values generate unwanted side-effects.

Example:

```
n <- 200
filled.contour(tdn, rdn, idn,
               col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red"))(n),
               levels = seq(0,1,length.out = n),
               plot.title=title(main="Detail", sub="detail", 
                                xlab="t", ylab="lambda"), 
               plot.axes = { axis(side = 1, at = tdn, labels = tdn)
                   axis(side = 2, at = rdn, labels = rdn) },
               key.title=title(main="ratio"),
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)))
```

Output:

[image]

Maybe experimenting with `lattice::levelplot` solves the problem. At least for the legend color key, a higher number of levels does not disturb. But the image is not 'smoothed'.

Example:

```
library(lattice)
levelplot(idn, row.values = tdn, column.values = rdn, cuts = n, col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red"))(n))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: So it is not possible to implemented expected plot in R? Is the expected figure plotted by `matlab` or `origin` or other language tools?

Comment: Maybe smoothing the matrix beforehand with something like `spatstat::blur` or other methods is possible.