# how to plot three dimension data or four dimension data to filled contour plot or surface plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, contour, surface

**ENV**

R 3.3.2

When I have data like **mini data 1**:

```
rdn<-c(0.8,1.8,2.8)
tdn<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

idn<-matrix(c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0.5, 0.7), nrow=9, ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

And the matrix looks like(3*9 = 27 data elements):

```
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 
0, 0.2, 0.5, 
0, 0.3, 0.6, 
0, 0.4, 0.6, 
0, 0.4, 0.6, 
0, 0.5, 0.7, 
0, 0.5, 0.7
```

Then I can get a filled.contour with parameters x,y,z. x is tdn, y is rdn, z is the matrix. [I already get this several month ago using filled.contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062811/how-to-make-colors-change-smoothly-when-plotting-in-r). rdn and tdn are only works as labels of x, y. The matrix seems be looks contours lines. And the matrix data is not a function of rdn and tdn.

[image]

**My current problem** is:

What If I have three dimension data **mini data 2**

```
r1dn<-c(0.8,1.8,2.8)
r2dn<-c(0.8,1.8,2.8)
tdn<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)
```

And (3*3*9 = 81 data elements):

```
 0.8                  1.8                  2.8
0.8  1.8  2.8       0.8  1.8  2.8        0.8  1.8  2.8

--------------- 81 ---- elements ----------------------

0.3, 0.3, 0.3,      0.3, 0.3, 0.5,       0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.4,      0.2, 0.4, 0.4,       0.4, 0.2, 0.5,
0.1, 0.1, 0.5,      0.2, 0.3, 0.5,       0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 
0, 0.2, 0.5,        0.2, 0.2, 0.6,       0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 
0, 0.3, 0.6,        0.3, 0.3, 0.6,       0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 
0, 0.4, 0.6,        0.2, 0.5, 0.7,       0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
0, 0.4, 0.6,        0, 0.5, 0.6,         0.5, 0.6, 0.9,  
0, 0.5, 0.7,        0, 0.6, 0.8,         0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 
0, 0.5, 0.7         0, 0.6, 0.8          0.5, 0.8, 0.9
```

I googled many surface and contour codes but I still not find some code for three dimension data yet. How to do that in R? Say, x is r1dn, y is r2dn, z is tdn, what about the three dimension data(I mean the 81 elements data)? Does ggplot can plot three dimension filled contour or surface plot? Or another alternative solutions?

All I expected is a 3d plot with color changes smoothly and no grid on it.

Looks like:

[image]

no grid for next three figures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Those should be 3d filled contour or 3d surface plot.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

IT LOOKS LIKE four dimension either after unfold all the data **mini data 2**:

```
r1dn   r2dn   tdn    fdn
 x,     y,     z,     f
0.8    0.8    0.1    0.3
0.8    0.8    0.2    0.2
0.8    0.8    0.3    0.1
0.8    0.8    0.4    0
0.8    0.8    0.5    0
0.8    0.8    0.6    0
0.8    0.8    0.7    0
0.8    0.8    0.8    0
0.8    0.8    0.9    0
0.8    1.8    0.1    0.3
0.8    1.8    0.2    0.2
0.8    1.8    0.3    0.1
0.8    1.8    0.4    0.2
0.8    1.8    0.5    0.3
0.8    1.8    0.6    0.4
0.8    1.8    0.7    0.4
0.8    1.8    0.8    0.5
0.8    1.8    0.9    0.5
0.8    2.8    0.1    0.3
0.8    2.8    0.2    0.4
0.8    2.8    0.3    0.5
0.8    2.8    0.4    0.5
0.8    2.8    0.5    0.6
0.8    2.8    0.6    0.6
0.8    2.8    0.7    0.6
0.8    2.8    0.8    0.7
0.8    2.8    0.9    0.7
1.8    0.8    0.1    0.3
1.8    0.8    0.2    0.2
1.8    0.8    0.3    0.2
1.8    0.8    0.4    0.2
1.8    0.8    0.5    0.3
1.8    0.8    0.6    0.2
1.8    0.8    0.7    0
1.8    0.8    0.8    0
1.8    0.8    0.9    0
1.8    1.8    0.1    0.3
1.8    1.8    0.2    0.4
1.8    1.8    0.3    0.3
1.8    1.8    0.4    0.2
1.8    1.8    0.5    0.3
1.8    1.8    0.6    0.5
1.8    1.8    0.7    0.5
1.8    1.8    0.8    0.6
1.8    1.8    0.9    0.6
1.8    2.8    0.1    0.5
1.8    2.8    0.2    0.4
1.8    2.8    0.3    0.5
1.8    2.8    0.4    0.6
1.8    2.8    0.5    0.6
1.8    2.8    0.6    0.7
1.8    2.8    0.7    0.6
1.8    2.8    0.8    0.8
1.8    2.8    0.9    0.8
2.8    0.8    0.1    0.3
2.8    0.8    0.2    0.4
2.8    0.8    0.3    0.4
2.8    0.8    0.4    0.4
2.8    0.8    0.5    0.5
2.8    0.8    0.6    0.5
2.8    0.8    0.7    0.5
2.8    0.8    0.8    0.5
2.8    0.8    0.9    0.5
2.8    1.8    0.1    0.3
2.8    1.8    0.2    0.2
2.8    1.8    0.3    0.4
2.8    1.8    0.4    0.5
2.8    1.8    0.5    0.5
2.8    1.8    0.6    0.6
2.8    1.8    0.7    0.6
2.8    1.8    0.8    0.7
2.8    1.8    0.9    0.8
2.8    2.8    0.1    0.3
2.8    2.8    0.2    0.5
2.8    2.8    0.3    0.5
2.8    2.8    0.4    0.6
2.8    2.8    0.5    0.7
2.8    2.8    0.6    0.7
2.8    2.8    0.7    0.9
2.8    2.8    0.8    0.8
2.8    2.8    0.9    0.9
```

Well, data **mini data 1** can be unfolded to three dimension either and can be plotted by filled.contour in 2d plot, so there should be a way 3d filled.contour to plot **mini data 2** right?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I tried to use your data but when you expand the grid you get a volume of points when you want a surface outlining the volume.

```
require(akima)
require(rgl)

r1dn<-runif(5, min = 3, max = 10)
r2dn<-runif(5, min = 0, max = 5)
tdn<-rnorm(5, 0, 5)

#interp is from the akima package so you can work with non-square data in your contour
  df <- as.data.frame(interp2xyz(interp(x=r1dn, y=r2dn, z=tdn)))

plot3d(df) # What it looks like in 3d

#what it looks like projected into 2d
  ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,z=z, fill=z)) + 
    geom_contour(binwidth=0.1, aes(color= ..level..)) + 
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: interp2xyz seems make the matrix data as a function of x,y,z ?  But, My data matrix is not a function of x,y,z.